# Hadoop: Slave nodes are not starting

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to setup a Pseudo Distributed Hadoop Cluster on my machine. 
Env Details :
Host OS: Windows
Guest OS: Ubuntu

- Vm's Created one master and one slave.
- I was able to run the hadoop wordcount successfully on single node cluster
- But when i tried to add the slave, the datanode, jobtracker, namenode and secondary namenode starts fine in the Master but no data node starts in the slave.

  - I am able to ping the slave and login to the slave using ssh from my master.
  - /etc/host file contains the correct entries in both vm's
  - I am using NAT and Host only Adapter to get a static ip for the VM's

---

Master Node = zenda1

Slave  Node = Zenda

---

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://zenda1:9000</value>
</property>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
 <configuration>
       <property>
               <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
               <value>zenda1:9001</value>
       </property>
 </configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
  <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>2</value>
    </property>
  </configuration>
```

**Master**

```
  zenda1
```

**Slave**

```
  zenda1
  Zenda
```

The hadoop folder is located at diff locations( folders location) in my Master and Slave nodes.

Comment: I have the same problem,
CentOS 7

All configurations are double-checked and the situation is like yours, hosts file is ok, I can ssh normally without pass and I copied the vm after first installation, so they are both in the same location
but when running hadoop I get only one node, instead of 2.
Hadoop version: 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution: The data nodes in the slave machines dint start because the location of hadoop home in my master and slaves were different. When I copied the hadoop home of slave node into the desktop ( thats where the hadoop home of my master node resides). It started working fine.

Comment: Accept your own answer then! It will give you some points ;=)