# No start of Hadoop components on the slave machine

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am trying to set up a multi-node hadoop cluster using my two laptops using [Michael Noll](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) tutorial. The OS on both machines is Ubuntu 14.04.

I managed to set up single-node clusters on each of the two laptops, but when I try to start (after all the necessary modifications as instructed in the tutorial) the multi-node cluster using `sbin/start-all.sh` on my master the slave does not react at all. All the five components on the master start, but no single one starts on the slave.

My `/etc/hosts` looks on both PCs like this

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.178.01  master
192.168.178.02  slave

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

(Furthermore, in /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop there was no file called master, so I created it using: `touch /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/master`)

Then, when I ru `sbin/start-all.sh`, I see the following:

```
hduser@master:/usr/local/hadoop$ sbin/start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
15/05/17 21:21:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [master]
master: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-master.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-master.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-master.out
15/05/17 21:21:46 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-master.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-master.out
hduser@master:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
3716 DataNode
3915 SecondaryNameNode
4522 Jps
3553 NameNode
4210 NodeManager
4073 ResourceManager
hduser@master:/usr/local/hadoop$
```

Interesting is here that on the line 6 there is `localhost`. Shouldn't it be master?

I can connect to the slave using `ssh slave`password-lessly from the master and control the slave machine, but still, `sbin/start-all.sh` does not start any hadoop components on the slave.

Very intrestingly, if I run `sbin/start-all.sh` on the slave, it starts NameNode **on the master (!!!)** and starts NodeManager and ResourceManager on the slave itself.

Can someone help me to properly start the multi-node cluster?

**P.S:** I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046509/hadoop-slave-nodes-are-not-starting), but in my case the location of hadoop home on both machines are identical

Comment: Can you post all your slave's logs? It will be very helpful for the diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: As I ran `sbin/start-all.sh` the logs of slave did not react at all. If you want them anyway I can upload them

Comment: You shouldn't use start-all anymore, and yes, in line 6, it should say `slave: starting datanode...`

Comment: Be careful, because the ip's showed here, doesn't match with what you say in one of your comments, that those ip's ends in 22 and 24...

Comment: My real IPs end in 22 and 24. Here I changed them according to instruction, but then replaced them by the real ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several things:

- Check that you can connect with `ssh` password-less from slave to master. Here is a [link](http://bigdatahandler.com/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-multi-node-cluster-setup/%20link) that teach us how to do it.
- The hostname of each machine is correct?
- /etc/hosts file is identical on both, master and slave, alike?
- Have you ckecked with ifconfig -a the ip of both machines? Are them the ones that you expected?
- Have you changed all the configurations file in slave machine, so instead of localhost, now must say the master's hostname? You should seek for the words `localhost` and stuff like that, in **all** your files on your `$HADOOP_HOME` directory, because there are several files for configurating all sort of things and it's very easy to forget some. Something like this: `sudo grep -Ril "localhost" /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop`
- Check the same as before but in master, so instead of saying localhost, it says the hostname of it.
- You should remove the `localhost` entry, on the `/etc/hosts` file on slave machine. Sometimes that entry, so typical of the hadoop tutorials, could lead to some problems
- In `masters` and in `slaves` @ slave host, it should say only "slave", and in your master host, in `masters` file it should say "master" and in your `slave` file, it should say slave.
- You should format your filesystem on both nodes previous to start hadoop.

Those are all the problems that i remember to have when i do the as you are doing right now. Check if some of them help you!

Comment: Hi chomp: (1) I enabled a password-less ssh access to master right now; (2) the hostname of the slave is `slave` and that of master is `master`; (3) `/etc/hosts` are identical, just the `localhost` is removed as you suggested; (4) the IP addresses are what I expect them to be: master's ends with 22 and slave's ends with 24; (5) the order gives me too much output, but suppose I replaced all `localhost`s by `master`. Now I reran `sbin/start-all.sh`, bu the same problem as before: all components on master start as they should but nothing on slave

Comment: I updated the question. I think it must be some detail, because the two PCs can communicate, and, strangely, when I start the cluster on the slave then some components start on the master... Note the `localhost` on the line 6 after running `sbin/start-all.sh`

Comment: Being more specific @DatamineR, in `/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop` you shouldn't have any reference to `localhost` in your configuration files (yarn-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml ). This applies to master and slave alike.

Comment: Probably that's the reason why you have in line 6 a reference to `localhost` instead of your slave.

Comment: In `masters` and in `slaves` file of your slave host, it should say only `slave`, and in your master host, in `masters` file it should say `master` and in your `slave` file, it should say slave. Also, you should format your filesystem on both nodes previous to start hadoop. I updated my answer with this advices.

Comment: Your last comment helped me! I checked again `slaves` and `masters` on both machines and now Nodemanager starts on my slave. Thanks a lot! :)